# Windows 8.1 ScriptNotify not working

Tags: c#, javascript, xaml, visual-studio-2013, windows-store-apps

I am stumped on an issue with  webview and scriptnotify

Server chap has put the following code in the web page:
javascript(alert) and javascript(confirm)

I put in a Debug Writeline to even see if the method is being called but it is not.

I can confirm that the https://webpage.com is in the Manifest as an accepted Uri.

Here is my code

XAML

```
    <Grid>
            <WebView x:Name="webView1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  ScriptNotify="MyWebView_ScriptNotify"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
</Grid>
```

C#

```
        public TeamPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            webView1.ScriptNotify += MyWebView_ScriptNotify;

           //other stuff
        }

 async void MyWebView_ScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("in here");
             var jsScriptValue = e.Value;
            MessageDialog msg = new MessageDialog(jsScriptValue);
            var res = await msg.ShowAsync();

        }
```

As said, the MyWebView_ScriptNotify is not even called??  There does not seem to be much examples on this issue so any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ScriptNotify does not fire on javascript alert or confirm.

It fires if the webpage does the following in JavaScript:

```
window.external.notify('some value');
```

Also see [description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.scriptnotify) and [sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-WebView-control-sample-58ad63f7) in MSDN

Edit: If you need to get notified about alert and confirm you could do something like this:

```
// do this after initialization of the webview
this.MyWebView.NavigationCompleted += MyWebView_NavigationCompleted;
...
async void MyWebView_NavigationCompleted(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationCompletedEventArgs args)
{
    // this will override the alert function with a function calling 
    // the window.external.notify function
    // you should be able to do the same with confirm
    string inject =
        @"window.alert = function(arg) {
            window.external.notify(arg);
        };";
    await MyWebView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new List<string>() { inject });
}
```

Comment: thanks Dennis. I will talk with the Server chap and rethink our way ahead.

Comment: @tjv I came up with another idea and edited the answer. This might accomplish what you need.

Comment: Thanks Dennis, passing onto the server chap now so we can test to see if it solves our issue.  Once sorted I will post an answer.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Talked with the server chap and it looks like we can not do it in my instance.  Dennis' solution is the answer if someone is looking for a similar solution, but if you want to use alert and confirm, then its not possible as far as I can tell.  That said, happy to be corrected and update this answer if corrected.